# Facebook Open Graph: How to Post User Message with Custom Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

The Facebook tutorials suggest that you can add a user comment to a custom action in a Facebook App. The example javascript function for posting is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postCook()
  {
      FB.api(
    '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook',
    'post',
    { recipe: 'http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html' },
    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occurred');
       } else {
          alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
    });
  }
  </script>
```

I have an "Endorse" action defined with the object "Local Business". Everything is working. Now I want to give the user the option to add a user message to their endorsement but I can not find any help in Facebook docs on how to implement this in the api (the above code). Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the 'message' parameter when publishing the action. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postCook(userMessage)
  {
    FB.api(
    '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook',
    'post',
    { recipe: 'http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html',
      message: userMessage },
    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occurred');
       } else {
          alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
    });
  }
</script>
```

will submit userMessage as a user provided message on the action.

The full list of supported parameters for the OpenGraph publishing API is available here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/#create

Comment: Thanks! This gets me a step closer but I'm still having trouble getting userMessage into the post.

Comment: Just for test purposes, tried populating the parameter with a text box with id="usermessage" and this: onclick="postEndorsement(document.getElementById('usermessage').value)" /> but I'm not getting the user message in my facebook timeline. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you enabled User Messages on the Open Graph action in the Facebook settings?

Comment: Yes. I've done that. Do I need to get the message into an og tag in the header?

Comment: OK, apparently the above onclick code is working. Thanks for your help! Send me a link to your website and I'll stick it in my blog. Blessings!